# How to add data coming from onActivityResult to the particular selected row of tablelayout in onCreate method?

Tags: android, tablelayout

```
final TableRow tr1_vin_details = new TableRow(this);
inspStatus = new ImageView(this);
tr1_vin_details.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 //TableRow tr = (TableRow) v.getParent();
 TableRow lTableRow = ((TableRow) v);
 TextView lTextView = (TextView) lTableRow.getChildAt(1);
 vinNum = lTextView.getText().toString();
 theTag = (Integer) v.getTag();
 Intent intent = new Intent(DeliveryInspectionActivity.this, ExceptionsActivity.class);
 //intent.putExtra("Row ID of a particular selected row:", rowId);
 intent.putExtra("Tag value", theTag);
 startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

}
});

Now I want to sending the row id(theTag) value to nextActivity, and in onActivityResult I want to add some data coming from NextActivity. Code is

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    id_row = data.getIntExtra("id of row:", 0);
    String str = String.valueOf(id_row);
    Toast.makeText(this, "You have selected row: " + " " + str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    int num_exceptions = data.getIntExtra("Number Of Exceptions", 0);
    TextView area_tv = new TextView(this);
    TextView type_tv = new TextView(this);
    TextView severity_tv = new TextView(this);
    if(num_exceptions > 0){
        inspStatus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ir_vin_red_check);
        tv_area.setText(Html.fromHtml("<br> Area: "));
        tv_area.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        tv_type.setText(Html.fromHtml("<br> Type: "));
        tv_type.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        tv_severity.setText(Html.fromHtml("<br> Severity: "));
        tv_severity.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        openedRow1.removeAllViews();
        openedRow1.addView(tv_area);
        openedRow1.addView(tv_type);
        openedRow1.addView(tv_severity);

        openedRow2.removeAllViews();
        openedRow2.addView(area_tv);
        openedRow2.addView(type_tv);
        openedRow2.addView(severity_tv);

        tl_skiddetails.addView(openedRow1, id_row);
        tl_skiddetails.addView(openedRow2, id_row);
    }
}
```

}

Now my question is I want to add openedRow1 & openedRow2 rows to table layout in onCreate method of FirstActivity when onclick of togglebutton in firstactivity

Where should I add these rows, in onActivityResult or onCreate method...? When I am adding this in OnActivityResult, the app is force closed.

06-04 12:40:58.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1642): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {net.mss.palsapp/net.mss.palsapp.DeliveryInspectionActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Please help me... I am struggling with this issue from a long...

Comment: you need to know what you need to pass in the argument .addview, what you are doing im not able to understand.

Comment: I am passing openedRow1 & openedRow2 rows to table layout. openedRow1 & openedRow2 contains the data that is coming from another activity...

Comment: and the id_row what you are passing with it, its the layout params which you need to pass, layout parms like layout_width and layout_height

Comment: no, uniqueID=0 & tr1_vin_details.setTag(uniqueID); and in onclick method I am calling getTag() method, theTag = (Integer) v.getTag();
 Intent intent = new Intent(DeliveryInspectionActivity.this, ExceptionsActivity.class);
 //intent.putExtra("Row ID of a particular selected row:", rowId);
 intent.putExtra("Tag value", theTag);
 startActivityForResult(intent, 0); and in onActivityResult, i am getting that data as id_row

Comment: please come online so dat we can chat. raksi004@gmail.com, invite for a chat

Comment: I want to know few things. what are you exactly trying to do, forget about the code here

Answer (score 1):

If u want to dynamically add table rows to the table layout follow the code below

```
// Get the TableLayout
    TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.maintable);

 // Create a TableRow and give it an ID
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
         tr.setId("unique id for table row");
        tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


         // Create a TextView to house the name of the province
        TextView labelTV = new TextView(this);
        labelTV.setId("unique id");
        labelTV.setText("your text");
        labelTV.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        labelTV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tr.addView(labelTV);


        // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```